# How to access the live view function using the Canon EDSDK

Tags: c#, winforms, edsdk, canon-sdk

I started learning C# a few weeks ago, n order to use the Canon EDSDK for a stop-motion program. Howerver I have no idea how to get  live view function, as the Canon documentation is bereft of ueful information and all tutorials are in unintelligible technobabble.

Please could someone tell me how to go about this task?

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Trying to use the Canon SDK may not be the best thing if you are just starting out, it is very difficult to work with and requires you to know about a few advanced topics.

Still, if you really want to do this, my tutorial on the Canon SDK on CodeProject is currently pretty much the only available thing: [Canon SDK Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp)

You'll find an example for Windows Forms in there and this is probably the best place to start. Download the project and just play around with it. You may find the current live view frame in the `MainCamera_LiveViewUpdated` method.